# Docker Pull fail in disconnected Enviornment

Tags: docker, openshift-origin

I have to install openshift on disconnected system so i followed following steps(original installation requires more image but for sake of understanding i am provided minimum steps)

1. on system with internet i did following steps

   - `docker pull docker.io/openshift/origin-node:v3.11.0`
   - docker save -o openshift-origin-v3.11.0-images.tar \
            docker.io/openshift/origin-node:v3.11.0
2. on second disconnected system i did following

   - `docker load -i openshift-origin-v3.11.0-images.tar`

Now when i start script for installation it pull the images with command `docker.io/openshift/origin-node:v3.11.0`

which is throwing following error

```
Error getting v2 registry: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on [::1]:53: dial udp [::1]:53: connect: no route to host
```

When on second system i do docker images

```
[root@x ~]# docker images
REPOSITORY                         TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
docker.io/openshift/origin-node   v3.11.0             14d965ab72d5        4 days ago          1.17 GB
```

Its showing me that image is available. Whats wrong here? My understanding is it should first look locally and then will check from dockerhub

**Update1:**
if i directly pull it saying

```
[root@x ~]# docker pull docker.io/openshift/origin-node:v3.11.0
Trying to pull repository docker.io/openshift/origin-node ...
Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.x.x:53: server misbehaving
```

I am expecting it should say

```
Status: Image is up to date for
```

Comment: is the `docker images` from the disconnected Env?

Comment: yes docker images is from disconnected

Comment: Can you try to retag the image with something like open shift:3.1 and retry installing this new image?

Comment: @Mihai if i retag then openshift installer would not understand new tag

Comment: Then there must be a reason why the installer only looks for that tag: to always download the latest version. Weird but... I'm sure redhat has its reasons for it :)

Comment: Could you please add the relevant parts of your installation script?

Comment: @bellackn regardless of installer if i directly do docker pull its still giving error, i provide details as Update1

Comment: I see you're expecting that it should say that the image is up to date. But how should Docker say that, if it's disconnected from the internet? It has no chance to check if that's true. :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed following in `/etc/containers/registries.conf` and it works
From

```
[registries.search]
registries = ['registry.access.redhat.com', 'docker.io', 'registry.fedoraproject.org', 'quay.io', 'registry.centos.org']
```

To

```
[registries.search]
registries = []

[registries.block]
registries = ['registry.access.redhat.com', 'docker.io', 'registry.fedoraproject.org', 'quay.io', 'registry.centos.org']
```